# BufferedReader is just waiting for the Clients response and not reflecting the code written above in actionPerformed

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, actionlistener, bufferedreader

I'm making a 2 player game using socket programming where I'm sending the moves as data from server to client and vice versa but when a move is made on server side, it still waits for the move of client side (Until data is not received from client side) and the changes made above the line of receiving data inside actionPerformed is not getting reflected.

Here is the declaration for BufferedReader:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

and here is the code where I'm facing problem:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

// some changes made like changing the color of buttons, adding texts on them, etc

String temp, move = "";
try {
    while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
        move += temp;
    }} catch (IOException ee) {
    System.out.println("Error in reading the move from player 2");
}
```

Here is the starting state of the game:
[Game Starting State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0b7e.jpg)

Here is the state which should occur after making a move (captured this state after removing that code of BufferedReader):
[State which should occur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrmRS.jpg)

Here is the state which I'm getting (See here the button is seen is pressed mode and other changes are not reflecting):
[State which is occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbCyr.jpg)

Can anyone help me with the solution!!!

Comment: Reading from a socket in an action listener doesn't begin to make sense, and reading it until end of stream makes even less sense. You haven't provided the peer code so it is impossible to comment further.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling this code which is *blocking* code:

```
while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

on the Swing event thread. When you do this, you block this thread from doing its important actions such as drawing the GUI, and this will cause your GUI to freeze. To prevent this from happening, such calls must be made within a background thread so as not to block the GUI's important event thread. Swing has a SwingWorker class that facilitates this, and I suggest that you look into using it. Please check out [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for the details.

Comment: Okay, I had a look into it but I got an alternative way to implement the thing I wanted, even though thanks a lot, got something new to learn which i wasn't aware to.